# Ti.Goosh - no messageCallback defined

Tags: android, notifications, appcelerator

I am facing some issues with this module, when the notification arrives, the callback method is throwing this:

[image]

The notifications arrives with no problem, but when i try to catch the "callback" event, throws that error.

Any help will be wellcome.
thanks in advance.

Titanium SDK 5.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was solved..
I just uninstalled the app on the device and run it again..